# Сглаживание нормалей

Tags: 3d, directx, шейдеры, direct3d

Я решил написать программу, которая придает плоскости рельеф с помощью карты высот и тесселяции, только освещение очень грубое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как я понял, нормали должны считаться так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я не могу это реализовать.

Короче, мне надо сгладить нормали.

Вот код шейдеров.

```
struct VS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : POSITION;
};

struct HS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXTURE;
};

struct DS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXTURE;
};

struct HS_CONSTANT_DATA
{
    float Edges[3] : SV_TessFactor;
    float Inside[1] : SV_InsideTessFactor;
};

struct GS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXTURE;
};

struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float3 Nrm : NORMAL;
    float2 Tex : TEXTURE;
};

cbuffer data :register(b0)
{
    float4x4 world;
    float4x4 viewProj;
    float4 factor;
    float2 lightPos;
    float relief;
}


Texture2D textureMap:register(t0);
Texture2D<float4> heightMap:register(t1);
SamplerState textureSampler {
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
    AddressW = Wrap;
};

HS_INPUT VS( VS_INPUT input )
{    
    HS_INPUT output = (HS_INPUT)0;
    output.Tex = (input.Pos + float4(12.5, -12.5, 0, 0)) / float4(25, -25, 0, 0);
    output.Pos = input.Pos;  
    return output;
}

float4 PS( PS_INPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    return textureMap.Sample(textureSampler, input.Tex) * saturate(dot(input.Nrm,normalize(float3(lightPos.x, lightPos.y, -1))) + 0.2);
}


HS_CONSTANT_DATA SampleHSFunction( InputPatch<HS_INPUT, 3> ip,
                                          uint PatchID : SV_PrimitiveID )
{    
    HS_CONSTANT_DATA Output;
    float tessFactor=factor.x;

    float TessAmount = factor.y;

    Output.Edges[0] = Output.Edges[1] = Output.Edges[2] = tessFactor;
    Output.Inside[0] =  TessAmount;

    return Output;
}

[domain("tri")]
[partitioning("pow2")]
[outputtopology("triangle_cw")]
[outputcontrolpoints(3)]
[patchconstantfunc("SampleHSFunction")]
DS_INPUT HS( InputPatch<HS_INPUT, 3> p, 
                    uint i : SV_OutputControlPointID,
                    uint PatchID : SV_PrimitiveID )
{


    DS_INPUT Output;
    Output.Pos = p[i].Pos;
    Output.Tex = p[i].Tex;
    return Output;
}


[domain("tri")]
GS_INPUT DS( HS_CONSTANT_DATA input, 
                    float3 UV : SV_DomainLocation,
                    const OutputPatch<DS_INPUT,3> TrianglePatch )
{
    GS_INPUT outP;
    outP.Pos=UV.x * TrianglePatch[0].Pos + UV.y * TrianglePatch[1].Pos + UV.z * TrianglePatch[2].Pos;
    outP.Tex = UV.x * TrianglePatch[0].Tex + UV.y * TrianglePatch[1].Tex + UV.z * TrianglePatch[2].Tex;
    outP.Pos.z = heightMap.SampleLevel(textureSampler, outP.Tex, 0, 0).x * relief;
    outP.Pos = mul(world, outP.Pos);
    outP.Pos = mul(viewProj,outP.Pos);  
    return outP;    
}

[maxvertexcount(72)]
void GS( triangle GS_INPUT input[3], inout TriangleStream<PS_INPUT> TriStream )
{
    float3 P1=input[0].Pos.xyz;
    float3 P2=input[1].Pos.xyz;
    float3 P3=input[2].Pos.xyz;
    float3 Nrm= normalize(cross(P2-P1,P3-P1));

    PS_INPUT A;
    A.Pos=input[0].Pos;
    A.Tex=input[0].Tex;
    A.Nrm=Nrm;

    PS_INPUT B;
    B.Pos=input[1].Pos;
    B.Tex=input[1].Tex;
    B.Nrm=Nrm;

    PS_INPUT C;
    C.Pos=input[2].Pos;
    C.Tex=input[2].Tex;
    C.Nrm=Nrm;

    TriStream.Append(A);
    TriStream.Append(B);
    TriStream.Append(C);
    TriStream.RestartStrip();
}
```

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: ниже присутствует удалённый (через очередь проверки) «ответ» от автора: *Сделал освещение через Normal Mapping - все заработало.*